# React-Native borderRadius is unuseful during animation through setState(...)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want the oval radius changing dynamically through the method `setState(...)`, but I find that the `borderRadius` is unuseless during this 
animation. So the shape becomes to a rectangule, which indicates that
the `borderRadius` attribute is unuseless.
Please tell me where am I wrong?

```
export default class Oven extends Component{
    render(){
        const {radius,backgroundcolor} = this.props;
        return(
          <View style={{
                      width: radius*2,
                      height: radius*2,
                      borderRadius: radius,
                      backgroundColor: backgroundcolor,
                      transform: [
                          {scaleX: 2}
                    ]}}>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You better use SVG or a canvas in a webview for these kinds of things.

Comment: you mean i should use a picture instead of rendering one?

Comment: svg is vector. You can animate that using RN animations. For any custom shapes you better use that. Use [this](https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-svg) or use React Native Art library which should already be in your react native modules by default.